# Flask Make Azure Blueprint - got an unexpected argument 'tenant'

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-active-directory

I am attempting to use Azure Active Directory to allow users from my company's Microsoft domain login to my Flask webapp. I was getting an error that said:

> Message: AADSTS90130: Application ... is not supported over the
>   /common or /consumers endpoints. Please use the /organizations or
>   tenant-specific endpoint.

So I did some research and found this [documentation](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#module-flask_dance.contrib.azure) which says I can set a "tenant" parameter, but when I run this:

```
blueprint = make_azure_blueprint(
    client_id="client_id_here",
    client_secret="client_secret_here",
    tenant="tenant_here"
)
```

I get an error that:

> TypeError: make_azure_blueprint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tenant'

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? How do I set the Azure tenant in Flask Dance?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this problem: I figured out that the library doesn't actually include a tenant argument by default. You can add it in by simply going into the azure.py file in the flask dance library and changing the two lines to read:

```
authorization_url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize".format(tenant=tenant),
token_url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token".format(tenant=tenant),
```